# Chrome extension add iframe and access parent window content

Tags: angularjs, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I inject a iframe from content script into a page. The iframe run an angular application. I want to access the parent window's content from this angular script. How can I do it?

Partial manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "css": [
            "css/inject.css"
        ],
        "js": [
            "scripts/inject.js"
          ],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": false
    }
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "frame.html"
]
```

frame.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/angular-csp.css" type="screen">
        <title>name</title>
    </head>

  <body>
    <div class="popup" ng-app="popup" ng-csp>
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it directly; cross-origin restrictions apply.

Instead, you need to message your content script to manipulate/query the page for you.

Comment: Can you please post an example?

Comment: Hard to do without knowing what you're trying to do; however, you should look into [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and [this function](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) specifically.